# Mysql UPDATE error that only affects first row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I use the sql UPDATE query, it only affects the first row of my members.

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `siteRank`");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
<?php
if($_POST['AccountUpdate'])
 {
        //mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE members SET username='$Username' WHERE id='$$IdentifcationNumber' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        echo $result['id'];
        echo $result['username'];
        echo 'separeator';
        echo $IdentifcationNumber;
 }
?>

<form method="post" action="viewprofile.php">
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Site Rank</th>
        <th>PyroCoins</th>
        <th>PIN</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date Joined</th>
        <th>Update Account</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="viewprofile.php">
    <tr>
        <td><input readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $result['id'];?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['username'];?></td>
        <td><input text="text" name="ChangePassword" value="<?php echo $result['password'];?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['browser'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['ip'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['siteRank'];?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ChangePyroCoins" value="<?php echo $result['PyroCoins'];?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['pin'];?></td>
        <td>
            Current Status:
            <input readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $result['status'];?>" />


            <select name="ChangeStatus">
                <option value="<?php echo $result['status'];?>"><?php echo $result['status'];?></option>
                <option value="[ Content Deleted ]">[ Content Deleted ]</option>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td><?php echo $result['date'];?></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="AccountUpdate" value="Update Account"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

</table>
</form>
```

My $_POST data should be self explanatory, but its only affecting the first row and not the row that Im trying to affect. When I click my html update button, it only displays only the first ID and not the ID or the account credentials that i'm trying to update. For example, When I try to edit somes details with an ID of 28, it affects the first table ID which is 1

Comment: You have a typo in the query, `$$` and you should remove the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. And you should remove the comment for the query, of course.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I fixed that and I'm still having the issue @JayBlanchard

Comment: I'm assuming that the code you're showing is viewprofile.php.

Comment: You just keep looping back and looking at the first record. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the form inside the WHILE loop. Every time you submit the form you re-query and start over with record 1.

Comment: Yes, it's going to the same page. @BigScar

Comment: I'm looping all the users so that I have them all right there to be able to update their information. why does it keep fixating itself on the first table row? @BigScar

Comment: as an aside, the html is badly formed - you have a form surrounding a table row but within the form you then close the table..... The form should either encase the entire table or be embedded within a td tag. Also, there are two forms - one nested within the other - again, this will cause problems

Comment: Where do you set the `$IdentifcationNumber`?

Comment: Where at? The form tags are surrounding the the whole table. @RamRaider

Comment: The Identification number was later added thinking that it would work. @dschniepp

Comment: @Isaak Markopoulos - really? To me it looks like there is a form enclosing the table, then another within the while loop that doesn't get closed, then the parent form ( I presume ) gets closed .... take a closer look

Comment: The `$IdentifcationNumber` is never set and it is the key in your condition, further more you want to update the `$Username` and its also an uninitialized variable. You need to pass the data from the form to the script.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that. I removed it thinking that would be my issue, but it wasn't. I have no idea what my issue it with my form looping back to the first table tow when I'm trying to pull data from other id's. @RamRaider

Comment: You can't have nested forms - they dont work

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_update_php.htm it will help you to understand how you can manipulate data via forms and write the data back to the database.

Comment: How is my form nested? @RamRaider

Comment: You ought to have a proper look at the code and perhaps try running it. There is a parent form surrounding the entire table ( this is fine ) - but when you begin the while loop you start another form which never gets closed, therefore you have badly nested forms and I don't wonder why the update doesn't work because there is no way to really know which form is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

'`ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`' in the query is unnecessary.

```
UPDATE members SET username='$Username' WHERE id='$IdentifcationNumber'
```

Comment: I tried that and removed the ORDER BY id desc and I changed all my SET variables and it still keeps updating the first table row.

Answer (score 0):

@Isaak Markopoulos - this is not tested but there are no nested forms so hopefully there should be less confusion when posting the form. The id field in the html has been named so at least there should be an id available in the posted vars

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>crazy little monkey</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        /* This only gets executed if it is a POST request */
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['AccountUpdate'] ) && isset( $_POST['IdentifcationNumber'] ) ){

            /* I assume this is the correct id - there was no name for the form element previously */
            $IdentifcationNumber=$_POST['IdentifcationNumber'];
            $sql="UPDATE members SET username='$Username' WHERE id='$IdentifcationNumber';";

            mysqli_query( $db, $sql );

            echo $result['id'];
            echo $result['username'];
            echo 'separeator';
            echo $IdentifcationNumber;
        }   
        /* This gets executed for any request */
        $query = mysqli_query( $db, "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `siteRank`;" );
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query );
    ?>
    <!-- parent table -->
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>Site Rank</th>
            <th>PyroCoins</th>
            <th>PIN</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Date Joined</th>
            <th>Update Account</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=12>
            <!-- begin a form / table for each row in rs -->
            <?php
                $rc=0;
                while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){
                    $rc++;
                    echo "
                        <!-- unique name for each form - not essential -->
                        <form name='vpf_{$rc}' action='viewprofile.php' method='post'>
                            <!-- nested child table fully contained within it's parent form element -->
                            <table>
                                <td><input type='text' name='IdentifcationNumber' readonly='readonly' value='".$result['id']."' /></td>
                                <td>".$result['username']."</td>
                                <td><input text='text' name='ChangePassword' value='".$result['password']."' /></td>
                                <td>".$result['email']."</td>
                                <td>".$result['browser']."</td>
                                <td>".$result['ip']."</td>
                                <td>".$result['siteRank']."</td>
                                <td><input type='text' name='ChangePyroCoins' value='".$result['PyroCoins']."' /></td>
                                <td>".$result['pin']."</td>
                                <td>
                                    Current Status:
                                    <input readonly='readonly' value='".$result['status']."' />
                                    <select name='ChangeStatus'>
                                        <option value='".$result['status']."'>".$result['status']."
                                        <option value='[ Content Deleted ]'>[ Content Deleted ]
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>".$result['date']."></td>
                                <td><input type='submit' name='AccountUpdate' value='Update Account'></td>                                  
                            </table>
                        </form>";
                }/* Close the while loop - note that the form(s) is/are FULLY contained within the loop - NO nesting */
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```